# Why does using a variable inside calc throw an invalid type error in a validator?

Tags: html, css, css-variables

I am trying to center a circle in CSS with the code below. Everything is working fine however when I run the code in the html validator from w3c (https://validator.w3.org/) I get two CSS errors that I cannot removed.

1. Error: CSS: top: Invalid type: var(--circleHeight) / 2.
2. Error: CSS: left: Invalid type: var(--circleHeight) / 2.

the error seems to come from the variable --circleHeight. The error is gone when I hard code 15vmax instead of `var(--circleHeight)`

I tried to move the variable around in my code. tried to add some () around and to use inset but nothing solved the issue.

here is the code(I am using styled-components for my CSS):

```css
::before {
    content: "";
    --circleHeight: 15vmax;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - var(--circleHeight) / 2);
    left: calc(50% - var(--circleHeight) / 2);
    height: var(--circleHeight);
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: var(--action-color);

    --scale-up: 1.2;
    animation: ${scaleUpAnimation} 7s var(--animation-timing-function) infinite
      alternate-reverse;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a fault in the validator - browsers are happy with the code and as you say it works OK.

Comment: The W3C validator is notoriously slow in accepting new properties and methodologies.

Comment: this is really weird because I am using the exact same code else where in my project and I don't have the error (height:  calc(var(--border-size) / 2)).

Comment: Found discussions on github with similar issues. https://github.com/validator/validator/issues/1284, https://github.com/w3c/css-validator/issues/355 It indeed looks like w3c nu validator doesn't sync with css validator. When test your css in https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ it doesn't show error, but displays warning "Due to their dynamic nature, CSS variables are currently not statically checked" in every line where css variable is used.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Taras. I think you are correct. I thought they were something wrong with my code since I used a similar logic elsewhere.